# Check if user read the .PDF file in Java

Tags: java, pdf, document

I have a Java program which handles a lot of .pdf type documents. I need to know if the user has read a document completely or not. Is there any meta tag in .pdf files or any other way to verify this?

Comment: Does the Java program itself display the PDF or would the user use a standalone PDF viewer to look at the document?

Comment: I have to analyse both possibilites. Of course it would be easier to me using a standalone PDF viewer but I can develop the other solution if necessary.

Comment: *"I need to know if the user has read a document completely or not"* - What do you mean by that? Obviously a program can hardly tell whether a user actually read each and every word in a document. Thus, what are your criteria?

Comment: I mean that the user has scrolled the whole document, not read every word. It should work the same way as several web pages showing you legal information and enable an "Accept" button once you scroll down all the text.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such "flag". The PDF itself does not care. You will need to emulate that, e.g. present the document in a manged view and consider "scrolled to bottom" as "read the entire document".